# SQL 2008 Express (R2): Creating an UPDATE trigger to update a table on another server?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, triggers, database-connection

I am just trying to think through a process I need where I have:

1. One SQL 2008 express database on a webserver - takes orders into an orders table
2. Another SQL 2008 express database on another webserver acting as a backend system to process the orders etc

The idea being that the webserver database can be left to do what it does, and only when a new order record is inserted (actually updated.. another part of the story) I wanted that row to be inserted to an orders table on another server...

The two servers do have local IP addresses, and are essentially on the same subnet - i.e. can communicate easily enough...

Just trying to work out if a SQL Trigger is the way to go, or do I have perhaps a scheduled job on the second server which queries the first server say every 5 mins (plenty, not too many orders) and inserts any new orders into it's own database.. the idea is the table in the source/first server has a bit field to indicate if that row has been seen/read by server two...

Any ideas?  unfortunately it's all SQL 2008 R2 express at this stage...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want a trigger accessing another server as part of a transaction. One solution, is to use [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx); have the trigger insert a message into the the local queue, and given the other server access to this queue.

> SQL Server Service Broker provides the
>   SQL Server Database Engine native
>   support for messaging and queuing
>   applications. This makes it easier for
>   developers to create sophisticated
>   applications that use the Database
>   Engine components to communicate
>   between disparate databases.
>   Developers can use Service Broker to
>   easily build distributed and reliable
>   applications.

Comment: +1 - gratulations to know abou this little gem that so mny overlook ;)

Comment: Hey thanks for this.  Actually I am finding out about a lot of new things around SQL 2008.  In the past I have used MSMQ, IBM/MQ Series etc, so the messaging concept is cool.. just never realised it was part of SQL 2008 (probably earlier versions!)

Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on linking servers first. This ought to be a [great article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3691721/Setting-up-a-Linked-Server-for-a-Remote-SQL-Server-Instance.htm) for you to start with. Better yet, the scenario it describes is actually fairly similar to yours. Also, replication between the two servers may be a better choice than triggers. Here's a [link for an article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3814591/Peer-to-Peer-Replication-in-SQL-Server-2008--Configure-a-two-node-topology.htm) doing just that.

Comment: Hey great articles!   I think in this case (and actually another project too) I am going with the broker concept.. actually in the past I was used to IBM MQ/Series & MSMQ for handling messaging, so with SQL 2008 R2 (prob earlier version too no doubt) having the broker/messaging built in, it works well.

Again, many thanks for taking the time to answer - much appreciated.